# Eliminating duplicates in collection

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, types

I have a declared collection of object type:

```
CREATE TYPE category_type AS OBJECT (
  col1   VARCHAR2(6),
  col2   VARCHAR2(10),
  col3   NUMBER);
/

CREATE TYPE category_tab AS TABLE OF category_type;
/
```

And in the PL/SQL code:

```
v_category_data     category_Tab := category_tab();
```

After I populate v_category_data, I find there are duplicates.  I need to remove them.  So, I have tried to work with MULTISET UNION DISTINCT by this:

```
v_new_data := v_category_data;
v_new_data := v_new_data MULTISET UNION DISTINCT v_category_data;
```

However, I get this error:

```
804/17   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'MULTISET_UNION_DISTINCT'
```

I tried using the MAP functionality, but did not understand how exactly to use it, or if it would help.

Does anyone know of a way to remove the duplicates in an object collection?

Comment: How are you populating the collection - can't you prevent the duplicates being included in the first place?

Comment: HI, I think **select into** is easier here. just select distinct into your variable

Comment: Have a look at SET function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions144.htm#i1269374

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiset union distinct` requires the elements of the collection to be comparable. In your case the elements are PL/SQL records that are unfortunately not comparable data structures (i.e. PL/SQL provides no build-in mechanism to compare PL/SQL records).

`multiset union` works because it doesn't need to compare the elements.

If for some reason you do not want to use distinct when you're populating your v_category_data collection then I advise to do as I have written below. Selecting from the collection and using distinct on the columns.

This is the part that interests you:

```
SELECT Category_type(col1, col2, col3) 
bulk   collect INTO v_new_data 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT col1, 
                        col2, 
                        col3 
        FROM   TABLE(v_category_data));
```

And this is the entire code with which I checked.

```
DECLARE

v_category_data CATEGORY_TAB := Category_tab(); 
v_new_data      CATEGORY_TAB := Category_tab(); 

BEGIN 

--populate the collection with 2 types of duplicates and print them
FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP 
    v_category_data.Extend(); 

    IF i < 4 THEN 
      V_category_data(v_category_data.last) := 
      Category_type('Test', 'Test', 1); 
    ELSE 
      V_category_data(v_category_data.last) := 
      Category_type('Test2', 'Test2', 2); 
    END IF; 
END LOOP; 

FOR i IN v_category_data.first..v_category_data.last LOOP 
    dbms_output.Put_line(V_category_data(i).col1 
                         ||' ' 
                         ||V_category_data(i).col2 
                         ||' ' 
                         ||V_category_data(i).col3); 
END LOOP; 

dbms_output.Put_line('After processing' 
                     ||Chr(10)); 

-- populate your collection using distinct and print the content
SELECT Category_type(col1, col2, col3) 
bulk   collect INTO v_new_data 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT col1, 
                        col2, 
                        col3 
        FROM   TABLE(v_category_data)); 

FOR i IN v_new_data.first..v_new_data.last LOOP 
    dbms_output.Put_line(V_new_data(i).col1 
                         ||' ' 
                         ||V_new_data(i).col2 
                         ||' ' 
                         ||V_new_data(i).col3); 
END LOOP; 

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

See below how we can achieve this :

```
CREATE TYPE category_type AS OBJECT (
  col1   VARCHAR2(6),
  col2   VARCHAR2(10),
  col3   NUMBER);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE category_tab AS TABLE OF category_type   ;
/

declare

v_category_data    category_Tab := category_tab();
v_new_data         category_Tab := category_tab();

begin
--Defining collection length
v_category_data.extend(3);

--Populating the collection
v_category_data(1):= category_type('A','B',1);
v_category_data(2):= category_type('A','B',1);
v_category_data(3):= category_type('B','C',2);

dbms_output.put_line('*********First Collection Elements**************');
for i in 1..v_category_data.count
 loop  
  dbms_output.put_line(v_category_data(i).col1 || v_category_data(i).col2 || v_category_data(i).col3 );
 end loop;

--Way to remove duplicate
 select 
      v_category_data MULTISET UNION DISTINCT category_Tab(category_type('A','B',1))
    into 
      v_new_data 
    from 
  dual;

--Displaying elements of second collection
dbms_output.put_line('*********Second Collection Elements**************');
for i in 1..v_new_data.count
 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(v_new_data(i).col1 || v_new_data(i).col2 || v_new_data(i).col3 );
 end loop;

end;
```

Output

```
SQL> /
*********First Collection Elements**************
AB1
AB1
BC2
*********Second Collection Elements**************
AB1
BC2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```